# transaction results in an account (0) without insufficient funds for rent

Tags: phantom, error

I am experiencing an error with Solana Phantom Wallet while using the wormhole.

transaction results in an account (0) without insufficient funds for rent

My balance contains 1000usdc and I also have enough sol for transactions.
How do I overcome this problem?
I need help.

I don't even know what account(0) is talking about here.
In my opinion, when I first bridged using Phantom on Wormhole Bridge, I created something called a token account. (Requested by wormhole) I think it's account(0).

Comment: Can you share the TransactionID so we can investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

I think account(0) is your current private key. Regardless, you have to have at least 0.05 SOL on that wallet after performing that transaction, transactions tend to fail on Solana if your wallet has less that 0.05 SOL.